# How OrbitDB, Gun, HyperDrive and BigchainDB differ from each other?

Tags: database, p2p

After some research, I found 5 most popular p2p databases, but still, don't understand how they differ from each other and which DB is better for certain cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OrbitDB](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db) is a **distributed DB** which uses **IPFS** to store data. You can think of IPFS as a distributed file system. IPFS is really interested. I encourage you to inspect IPFS.

[BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com) uses **blockchain** technology to store data. It is a decentralized DB.

[Gun](https://github.com/amark/gun) seems like a **P2P DB** in which user stores data and it features **p2p synchronization** to keep data in sync.

[HyperDrive](https://github.com/mafintosh/hyperdrive) is a **P2P file system** that you can copy files to other computers.

Comment: Re BigchainDB, I'm not sure how true that is, as production deployments of BigchainDB are told to use MongoDB behind the scenes. Seems BigchainDB is just a sync layer on top of MongoDB

Comment: orbitdb also keeps data in sync between peers